# How to display desktop on TV by RDP connect

Tags: mac, windows-10, remote-desktop, hdmi, remote-connection

I use `Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.28` on Mac to connect the Win10 PC, a TV connect the Win10 PC through HDMI.

I want to display the windows on TV and control by mac. However, when I use Mac connect the Win10, the app on my mac is logged in and the Win10 PC directly log out and display the `Time Page`(without login). At the same time, the TV also display the `Time Page` as same as Win10 PC, which do not display the desktop in the `Remote Desktop` on mac.

Is there a solution for that? Thanks

Comment: your tv needs to be connected to your mac, not your windows 10 pc because when you login with rdp local user on Win10 PC logs out and lets you login remotely. IF HDMI isn't possible then i'd suggest you consider miracast.

Comment: Team viewer allows the remote screen to stay 'live'.

Comment: Yes but as long as you stay on a free plan it's slow and tends to disallow prolonged connections.

Comment: This is not going to work well using `rdp`. You would have closer results with applications like `TeamViewer` or `VNC`. However, any remote connection (even on LAN) will likely be unable to transmit the video quality you would like. Most frames will be dropped.

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ thanks for your answer. Which I want is remote control, if I connect TV through mac, that's not meaningful.

Comment: @Tetsujin @root that's thanks for your answers. That's best way I found now, using `TeamViewer`. video quality is a issue, but it's not important. The only problem is it doesn't work without internet, right?

Comment: @Stephen doesn't your tv support wireless display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design feature of Windows' RDP protocol.  RDP does not "shadow" user sessions the way other remote access programs do.  When connecting via RDP to a remote machine, you get a session that is distinct from the console login.

Additionally, with the Workstation editions of Windows (e.g. Windows 10), RDP is limited to a single session (as opposed to a server, which lets you have multiple sessions).  Therefore, when you remote in, the local console always locks.

There are only two ways to accomplish what you're trying to do:

- Connect the TV to your Mac instead of your PC.
  -- OR --
- Use a different remote control software (such as TeamViewer or LogMeIn) that does allow you to shadow user sessions.